# How do I hide and unhide a link on a jsp page based on the value of another label on the same jsp using beans?

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

How do I hide and unhide a link on a jsp page based on the value of another label on the same jsp?

Comment: Use Jquery for show and hide HTML DOM.

Comment: Can you please show us the code that you are using for creating that link ?

Comment: Where is your code? what have you tried? what technologies have you used?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Expression Language with beans.

```
<label for="...">${myBean.label}</label>

<c:if test="${myBean.label eq ''}">
    ...
</c:if>
```